# How can I create a view like this? (Canvas or D3js)

Tags: d3.js, canvas

This is the first time I've encountered something like this, and according to my research the easiest way to make it happen is d3.js. I even don't know how to describe this view/chart, so I added its picture.

[image: Chart View]

Is there a common chart name given to this? Does canvas or d3.js lead me to the result easier?

I looked at the examples on this page, but I couldn't see an example close to what I need.

https://observablehq.com/@d3